Axiom of Choice in characterizing openness in subspace
Below is the typical characterization of open sets in a subspace $Y$ of a metric space $X$.

$E$ is $Y$-open iff there exists an $X$-open $S$ such that $E = S \cap Y$.

The forwards direction usually comprises choosing a $Y$-neighborhood for each point in $E$ and then considering the union of their corresponding $X$-neighborhoods. More precisely, for each $p \in E$, the set $\mathcal{R}_p = \{r :N^Y_{r_p} \subseteq E\}$ is non-empty. Choosing $r_p \in \mathcal{R}_p$, consider the set $S = \bigcup_{p \in E} N^X_{r_p}$.
However, this argument clearly requires the axiom of choice. I am wondering if one could bypass it by specifying an explicit radius. Obvious candidates are the infimum and supremum, but the infimum could be zero and the set is not necessarily bounded.

Fix an injection $f\colon\mathbb{Q}_{\gt 0}\to \mathbb{N}$. For example, you can use the usual zig-zag counting, or you can use an explicit well-order the positive rationals, e.g. using height.
For each $p\in Y$, let $\mathscr{R}_{p,\mathbb{Q}}=\{r\in\mathbb{Q}_{\gt 0}\mid B^Y(r,p)\subseteq Y\}$, where
$$B^Y(r,p) = \{y\in Y\mid d(y,p)\lt r\}$$
is the open ball of radius $r$ around $p$ in $Y$.
For each $p$, let $r_p = \min(f(\mathscr{R}_{p,\mathbb{Q}}))$. Now proceed as before.

So it's really the well-ordering principle at work!

@n1lp0tence: The well-ordering principle is a very broad statement about all sets, and is equivalent to the axiom of choice. You don't need that to produce an injection $\mathbb Q_{>0} \mapsto \mathbb N$. You can write down an actual mathematical formula for that injection.

oh not the well-ordering theorem, i meant the one stating that any countable set could be well-ordered, which is equivalent to induction
